# Check if a spreadsheet control in an UserForm is empty or if all the cells are blank

Tags: excel, vba

Placed a SpreadSheet Control and a ComboBox in an UserForm. I want to check if all the cells in this spreadsheet control are empty. I have tried several possibilities and variations I could find, but none works. This was the last attempt. No errors are generated, but nothing happens though.

```
Sub check_if_empty()

Dim rngSource As Object 
Dim TEST1 As String

TEST1 = CmbBox1.text

Set rngSource = Spreadsheet1.Sheets(TEST1).Range("A2:A2001")

If rngSource Is Nothing Then

     MsgBox "This spreadsheet control is empty"

  Else

     MsgBox "There is at least one value"

end if
end sub
```

Comment: Nothing happens?You don't get an error or a message box? That seems... very improbable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `WorksheetFunction` to run `CountA()` against the range as a test:

```
Sub check_if_empty()    
    Dim rngSource As Range 'range is a range
    Dim TEST1 As String

    TEST1 = CmbBox1.text

    'May need to add Spreadsheet1 workbook(?) object back in here
    Set rngSource = Sheets(TEST1).Range("A2:A2001")

    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rngSource) = 0 Then
         MsgBox "This spreadsheet control is empty"
    Else
         MsgBox "There is at least one value"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I had to replace your line of code `Set rngSource = Sheets(TEST1).Range("A2:A2001")` with `Set rngSource = Spreadsheet1.Sheets(TEST1).Range("A2:A2001")`. Therefore, I had to include `Dim rngSource As Object`. The message I receive is "There is at least one value", but the SpreadSheet within the UserForm is empty. I did no mention, but I have a Worksheet called "TEST1" in my Workbook, so, it is compulsory that I differentiate that sheet from the Spreadsheet control TEST1 inside de Userform. So, the problem continues. Another suggestion?